# Handling empty sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My textbook says that A = {{},A} is not the same as B = {A}.

It says that in the first example the empty set is a member of A and in the second one the empty set is just a subset of B.

I do not understand how can he say that, if he just said before that no subset is a member of another set and he also says that the empty set is a set. So my reasoning is that it is not possible for the empty set to be a member of any set but a subset of every set.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $A=\{\{\},A\}$ in the first formula? In standard set theory there is no set $A$ with this property.

Comment: The sets $B=\{A\}$ and $C=\{\{\},A\}$ are indeed different.  For a very informal explanation, a bag containing only an apple is different than a bag containing both an apple and another bag.

Comment: The left hand side has two elements and the right hand side has one.

Comment: A subset could be a member; disallowing that would be too much for expressiveness of set theory. There are useful special sets $s$ whose definition exactly states $\forall a(a\in s\Leftrightarrow a\subset s)$.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "no subset is a member of another set" is not remotely correct - it sounds like you're misremembering or misunderstanding what your textbook said. It *is* true to say *subsets and members are not the same* - that is, something can be a member of another set without being a subset, and something can be a subset without being a member. This case is a good example; $\{\}$ is a subset of $B$, but not a member. On the other hand, $A$ is a member of $B$, but not a subset (provided $A$ is nonempty, at least). On the other hand, $\{\}$ is both a member and a subset of $\{\{\},A\}$.

Comment: What it says precisely is that "Sets can be inside sets but are not counted as individuals" I think I might have confused "Individual" with "members". Is then correct to say that no set can be an individual but a set can be a set and a subset of other sets? Thanks!

Comment: @CésarDalíVázquezNavarro The sentence is poorly written as is. I would wager that you've correctly understood their meaning of "individual" as "member". I'd guess that what they meant was "It is possible that a set $S$ can be a subset of another set $T$, while not being a member of $T$". The sets $\varnothing$ and $B$ in the OP give an example of this.

Comment: @CésarDalíVázquezNavarro It's hard to say - the use of the word "individual" here isn't really standard. If I had to guess, I would say that the phrase "Sets can be inside sets but are not counted as individuals" is just intended to say that subsets don't count as members of a set (so $\{1,2\}$ has only two elements, even though it has three proper subsets).

Comment: Another point they could be emphasizing is that the set $\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$ has only three elements, not four.  The three elements are $1, 2$ and $\{3,4\}$ respectively.  In this case, $\{3,4\}$ is counted as *an* element of $\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}$, but not as multiple elements (*despite $\{3,4\}$ being a two-element set itself*).

Comment: @DuncanRamage I suppose you are right, I decided to move to a more formal book on the matter. I came to realize that even I move slower, I am more confident that I do not get confused. Thank you for taking the time to answer and happy holidays.

Comment: @Reese thanks for the feedback. Some of the confusion I have here I think it is with the names of the concepts. I moved to a more formal book and I am doing better.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of subset:

*A set $A$ is a subset of a set $B$ if all elements of $A$ are elements of $B$.*

If we look at the empty set, we can see that the definition applies. All elements of the empty set are contained inside any given set $B$, because there aren't any elements of the empty set.

The empty set is not a *member* of a set $B$ in general. This would mean that the empty set is actually one of the elements of $B$, which obviously it isn't.

In the examples you've got, in one case the empty set is an element, and in the other it's a subset.

Comment: Technical comment: somewhere along the way you have to deduce $A \neq \varnothing$ to make the argument work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Given the context, I find it's worth emphasizing for the reader that one cannot just assume $A$ and $\varnothing$ are different simply because they're notated differently; this is something that must actually be established (of course it's very easy to do so in this case). Such a fact is necessary, for example, for it to be obvious that $\varnothing \notin B$.